# Protect the API by token/api key

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, api-key

A newbie question about API security:

When I applied API service from some API providers, usually I just login and generate an api key or token in their api management site. After that I can embed this api key or token in the request to access the API.

I was told that the this is OAuth 2. But, after reading a few articles about OAuth 2, it seems the OAuth-2 token issued from OAuth server will expire and a refresh-token is required to fetch a new token.

But the API keys I got from those API providers does not mention about the expiration, instead, I can manually revoke the API Key on their API management site.

So, if I have some APIs which I want to use the similar way (let the user manage their own api key on my site) to protect, how can I achieve that by using the OAuth 2 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you explained above are 2 different ways to authorize a request:

**A. Using API Keys**

- These API keys are usually a long string that you generate inside a dashboard
- You as a developer would usually have 1 API key throughout your app, and you append this API key to requests to the API provider

**B. Using OAuth 2.0**

- OAuth 2.0 uses a different kind of token to authorize requests, it usually involves a short-lived access token and long-lived refresh token.
- These tokens are usually for Users, each user will have a different token that expires every X days.
- To acquire a token, the user has to "log in" to your site or an Identity Provider's site (like Google Accounts) and enter their credentials every time the token expires.

#### Here's a picture to show the difference:

[image: OAuth 2.0 vs API Keys]

If you want to provide an API service for other developers:

- **Use OAuth 2.0 to log in the developers** to their dashboard (this means your server routes that interact with the dashboard would be protected by the OAuth 2.0 tokens, requiring the developer to log in to update some settings)
- **Use API Keys to access your provided API routes**. Developers have to log in and generate API keys from the dashboard. Then they can use this API key to fetch resources from your API.

Here's a more thorough explanation about [OAuth 2.0, access tokens, and how to implement it on your site](https://blog.cotter.app/what-on-earth-is-oauth-super-simple-intro-to-oauth-20-access-tokens-and-how-to-implement-it-in-your-site/).

Comment: Reference is throwing 404. 
Also, Can you point me to some resource where I can get an understanding of how the API Key thing works, please?
I've been thinking to do something like-> Generating a key, Storing it in DB, and on every request check DB for the same.
But it seems like it's not the right way to query DB for every request.